# send unsigned char * using PyObject_CallMethod

Tags: python, c++, pyobject

I'm struggling with `PyObject_CallMethod` trying to send `unsigned char *` to python script, but it gives me error calling the method on the python side. I've tried `s,s#,s*,y` and `B` formats but with no luck. which format should I use?

Here's the reference I'm looking at https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that performs the call to `PyObject_CallMethod`?

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your specific problem as required here please, include all error messages verbatim, and don't forget to narrow the code to the least necessary to reproduce exactly the problem. Thank you for flying with _Stack Overflow Airways_ and obey all our security instructions seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I had to `memcpy` the `unsigned char *` with known size to `unsigned char[KNOWN_SIZE]` and then send it based on this link: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html , I had to send the array with this flag `'s#'` where `s` refers to the type of the type of the first parameter and `#` is the size of the first parameter.